# Is it OK to use 15 amp receptacles with 12 gauge wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

Is it OK to use 15 amp receptacles with 12 gauge wire?

With a 15 amp breaker?
With a 20 amp breaker?

Comment: For the USA I've found https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Electrical-Wiring-Residential-Commercial/dp/0971977984 to be very valuable. Your local library may have it.

Comment: If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept.

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking about wiring in conformance with the USA National Electrical Code, 15 amp receptacles are often used with 12 gauge wire. The only problem may be in using the quick-connect feature where you just stick the wire in a hole and it is automatically caught and retained. Those are only for 14 gauge wire. With 12 gauge, you need to use the screw terminals. You can use 15 amp outlets on either 15 or 20 amp circuits. 12 gauge wire is the minimum for 20 amp circuits. 14 gauge wire is the minimum for 15 amp circuits. Knowing the proper wire size is only one of many requirements for wiring. If you have to ask about that, there are probably other things that you don't even know to ask about. Do you know how to determine how many wires are allowed in a given size box?

Comment: Also, don't underestimate the difficulty of working with the stiffness of solid AWG12 within the confines of a typical outlet or switch box. I once had the idea that I would use it exclusively for new wiring, just to be conservative, but I quickly gave up on that idea after doing a few circuits with it.

Comment: @Dave Tweed; I had that experience, but it was my brother who decided to run AWG12 everywhere and leave the device wiring to me.

Comment: You have my sympathy!

Comment: Just don't use the "backstab" connectors, whether using 15 or 20 amp outlets on 12 or 14 gauge wire. They only clamp with a thin spring of metal that will work well for a limited time. Once they start to work loose, they're a potential source of fire-starting arcs. If it's a straight in connection that is then screwed down, those are good (and much easier than making the loop in the end of the wire).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with what has been said previously. However, there is an exception not mentioned: If a 20 amp circuit has only one simplex outlet, that outlet must be a 20 amp outlet. A simplex outlet is typically used for a dedicated circuit, which serves only one appliance.

> 210.21 (B)(1) Single Receptacle on an Individual Branch Circuit.
>
> A single receptacle installed on an individual branch circuit shall
> have an ampere rating not less than that of the branch circuit.